# where to point CNAME entry for cloudfoundry routes distinguished by path?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

We run multiple applications in Cloudfoundry.
Now we have the requirement to distinguish app requests by path - this is clearly possible by using

```
cf create-route myspace mydomain.com –hostname myapp –path foo
cf map-route my-app mydomain.com –hostname myapp –path foo
cf create-route myspace mydomain.com –hostname myapp –path bar
cf map-route my-another-app mydomain.com –hostname myapp –path bar
```

now the requests are routed like this:

- http://myapp.mydomain.com/foo -> my-app
- http://myapp.mydomain.com/bar -> my-another-app

but to make this all work, I also need a DNS entry to resolve `myapp.mydomain.com`, to where do I point the CNAME record e.g. on cloudflare for `myapp.mydomain.com`?

`my-app.scapp.io` or `my-another-app.scapp.io` do not look correct, because its not one or the other I want to address, but both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd make a CNAME record that points to the default route assigned to your app. It looks like `my-app.scapp.io` in your example above, but you can run `cf app <name>` and find the assigned route.

Because you're using path-based routing, you'd only need one CNAME record for both apps. It would then be up to the client to select the correct path such that they are routed to the right application.

Comment: I understand I only need one CNAME, but why `my-app.scapp.io` and not `my-another-app.scapp.io`? what if I delete the app behind `my-app.scapp.io`, do I have to change my CNAME entry?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't really matter which of the two you pick, but the CNAME has to point to one thing. See https://serverfault.com/a/574077. Another option would be to control the default route that's generated and use path-based routing there as well. Ex: my-app.scapp.io/foo and for the second app my-app.scapp.io/bar. Then you remove the second domain altogether (if I'm following your line of questioning).